# Why won't a Nullable Public Property in a VB.net Class accept 0 (zero) as Assignment?

Tags: vb.net, nullable

I have a nullable public property on a class using Vb.net 3.5:

```
    Public Property TicketCharge() As Nullable(Of Decimal)
        Get
            If _TicketCharge = Nothing Then
                Return Nothing
            Else
                Return _TicketCharge
            End If
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Nullable(Of Decimal))
            If value.HasValue Then _TicketCharge = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

There's a method that assigns the value.  It works fine, except for when I try to assign the value 0 (zero) to it.

```
    If FundBuySell = "Exchange $" Or FundBuySell = "Exchange Shares" Then
            TicketCharge = 0
    Else
```

When I assign zero and then retrieve it, it shows the property = nothing.

I need the property to be Null sometimes and Zero sometimes.  Can someone explain what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `If _TicketCharge = Nothing` is not doing what you expect (inflammatory comment: as it always is with VB.NET; sorry guys, couldn't resist it). You either need `If _TicketCharge Is Nothing` or `If Not _TicketCharge.HasValue`

Comment: if I use _TicketCharge Is Nothing, I get this error: "Is operator does not accept operands of type Decimal. Operands must be reference or nullable types."

If I use _TicketCharge.HasValue, I get this error: "HasValue is not a member of Decimal"

Comment: You never told that your _TicketCharge is Decimal, not Nullable(Of Decimal).

Comment: I don't understand.  It is Nullable(of Decimal) -- as shown above. All I changed was "_TicketCharge = Nothing" to "_TicketCharge Is Nothing".

Comment: I got it! Sorry.  A little slow sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

To explain further:

Nothing pulls double duty in VB.Net as both the "null" value for reference types and the "default" value for value types.  When you use "=" rather than "Is" or "HasValue", you're forcing it into the value-type role, and so the Nullable class will compare it to it's current stored value (including throwing an exception if no value is set!).  Since the default value of a Decimal is 0, the comparison at the top of your `Get` accessor evaluates to True.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the way that you are comparing _TicketChange in order to determine if it has a value.  Nothing has several meanings in VB.Net as it represents both an empty value and reference type.  Doing boolean logic with Nothing and a Nullable will lead to often unexpected behavior.

Instead use _TicketChange.HasValue.

Answer (score 1):

Finally this worked:

```
If Not IsDBNull(var)
```